# How do I use 'Django Forms' to process user input?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, user-input, crud

I am creating a kind of dashboard which, when it's finished, will allow the user to (1) upload a profile picture, (2) Enter a displayname for themselves, and (3) Edit and change their profile picture as well as their displayname should they want to.

https://github.com/pmahalan/Avybe_Database_Project

I have the front-end built out (the template and view), and I have the model built out. The I labeled the model "creator", as in content creator - the two objects associated with it are "name" (corresponds to their displayname) and "upload" (corresponds to their picture).

I also have URL paths associated with the submit and upload buttons, which do work when clicked on.

**However, clicking submit after typing in a new username or uploading a new picture still doesn't actually make a *change* to the person's info. I can alter the info if I personally do it through Django Admin, but that's it. I want the frontend user to be able to effectively change it through their input and when they click the "submit" buttons.**

Do I create the Django within my views.py file? Do I create two separate forms (one for the display name and one for the profile picture), or just one? From there, how do I pass it on to my template? Does there need to be an "if" statement to see if it's a POST or GET request?

**my views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
from .models import *

def home(request):
    creators = Creator.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {'creators': creators})

def changeName(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)

def uploadPic(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', context)
```

**My urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home),
    path('update_name/', views.changeName, name="update_name"),
    path('upload_pic/', views.uploadPic, name="upload_pic"),
]
```

**My template (dashboard.html):**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Avybe Creator Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>

  <p class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;"> &nbsp; </p>
  <!-- Deliberatley empty space -->

    <h1 class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;">Welcome to your Avybe Creator Dashboard!</h1>

    <p class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;"> &nbsp; </p>
    <!-- Deliberatley empty space -->

    <form action="" method="POST" class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      Upload a Profile Picture: &nbsp;
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit" href="{% url 'upload_pic' %}">
    </form>

    <p class="row"> &nbsp; </p>
    <!-- Deliberatley empty space -->

    <p class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;">Your current displayname is: 
      {% for i in creators %}
          {{i.name}}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <p class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;"> &nbsp; </p>
    <!-- Deliberatley empty space -->

      <form action="" method="POST" class="row" style="padding-left: 60px;">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <label for="publicname">Edit your displayname: &nbsp; </label>
          <input type="text" id="publicname" name="publicname" value="ExampleName">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" href="{% url 'update_name' %}"> 
        </form> 
  

</body>
</html>
```

**My model:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Creator(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    upload = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Make sure name attribute inside input element has same name as the field name for that input inform.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, I am also new to Django, but instead of making forms yourself with input fields, Django has its own way of making forms that I would recommend. In order to make a form using Django, you have to create a new class, such as:

```
class edit_name(forms.Form):
    new_name = forms.CharField(label="Enter Your New Name")
```

Then, in your views.home function (or wherever you want the form), you can add a line generating a blank form, like so:

```
form=edit_name()
```

And then in your context, add `'form': form`
That way in your HTML file, instead of writing all the input, you just have to do `{{ form }}` and Django will automatically generate the form for you. Now, in order to receive the data this form provides, you can add this code to the views function which is processing the POST request, in your case, it is update_name (only focusing on one form).

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = edit_name(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data['new_name']
```

Now, you have the title variable with the data the inputted which you can now do whatever you want with it, like editing some file, and then returning a httpredirect, render, or response.

Hope this helped!
P.S. If there are any errors in my code, I'm sorry, as I said I am a bit of a Django noob myself. Also, sorry if I missed a step, in order to learn about forms and Django in general a little more thoroughly, I would recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8q0C-C1js4&feature=youtu.be&t=4833s) lecture.